# Prettier not working on saving file after vscode update

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, prettier

[image: when I try to save my file this red box shows and no indentation happens]

> I have pasted my JSON setting, which may help you to get a deeper knowledge of my problem
> when I try to save my file this red box shows and no indentation happens

```
    {
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
  "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled",
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.fontSize": 20,
  "editor.linkedEditing": true,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "highlight-matching-tag.styles": {
    "opening": {
      "left": {
        "underline": "yellow"
      },
      "right": {
        "surround": "#155FFA"
      },
      "name": {
        "highlight": "rgba(180, 20, 80, 0.3)"
      }
    },
    "closing": {
      "full": {
        "custom": {
          "dark": {
            "borderWidth": "0 0 3px 0",
            "borderColor": "yellow",
            "borderStyle": "solid",
            "borderRadius": "4px",
            "right": "10px"
          },
          "light": {
            "borderWidth": "0 0 3px 0",
            "borderColor": "yellow",
            "borderStyle": "solid",
            "borderRadius": "5px",
            "right": "10px"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "prettier.semi": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark",
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,

  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

> jglglaoyiughlva oaoiuoya aoiutooya gouyoauoyuaoo jglglaoyiughlva oaoiuoya aoiutooya gouyoauoyuaoojglglaoyiughlva oaoiuoya aoiutooya gouyoauoyuaoojglglaoyiughlva oaoiuoya aoiutooya gouyoauoyuaoojglglaoyiughlva oaoiuoya aoiutooya gouyoauoyuaoojglglaoyiughlva oaoiuoya aoiutooya gouyoauoyuaoo

Comment: It came to my knowledge and prettier works fine for js and CSS but fails to format HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

> I came up with the solution to my problem by myself, all I had to do was paste the following code in the JSON setting of vs-code for prettier work on HTML and JSON files.
> I hope it works for you. cheers

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
}
```